# What effect has a grant command when no schema is specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically I tried to grant permissions to all schemas in a database to a user I have created before like so

```
USE MyDatabase
GO 

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, EXECUTE, DELETE TO MyUser -- note that no schema is specified
GO
```

Now, the effect is quite confusing. According to SSMS `MyUser` has the follwing effective permissions on `MyDatabase`: CONNECT, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, SELECT.

However, he doesn't seem to have rights on any Schema. So my question is, what is the effect of the `GRANT` from above and is there any way to `grant` permissions on every `schema` in a database (sth. like a wildcard)?

Comment: You *didn't* specify any schema so the user's default schema was used. Typically this is `dbo`

Comment: thanks for your response. i just found out, that i actually seem to have privileges on the schemas. but this is not showing up in mmsm...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: no, it's not on the default schema. It's on the entire database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out which permissions were granted using the following query:

```
SELECT d.*, OBJECT_NAME(major_id) AS ObjectName, SCHEMA_NAME(major_id) AS SchemaName 
FROM sys.database_permissions d 
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals u ON d.grantee_principal_id=u.principal_id 
WHERE u.name='MyUser'
```

In this case, the permissions were granted on the entire database, which is the same thing as granting those permisions on each schema.